# RDP: Black screen and "failed to reconnect to your remote session"

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I got a problem that I've spend most of today trying to fix, but unable to. I connect remotely to a computer, which is running Windows 10, but randomly it will stop working. It always fixes it when I reboot, but not for long until it starts again.

It will just show a black screen for 30 seconds or so (not responsive no matter what I do) and then say "failed to reconnect to your remote session".

The only errors I can find in Event Viewer are these:

```
'Failed CreateVirtualChannel call on this Connections Stack' in CUMRDPConnection::CreateVirtualChannel at 2958 err=[0xd0000001]
```

and

```
'Failed GetConnectionProperty' in CUMRDPConnection::QueryProperty at 3344 err=[0x80004001]
```

I have tried disabling UDP and RemoteFX. All my drivers are up-to-date.

Any other ideas?